# zxing - which permissions are needed for a specific scan feature

Tags: android, android-permissions, zxing

I inherited code that I need to maintain. among all tasks, I need to add check permission code.

among many needed permissions I have

```
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I believe it comes from using zxing code, because I saw this permission in zxing sample code,
e.g.

- https://www.programmersought.com/article/6696481020/
- https://github.com/alibaba/weex/pull/1111/files
- ... and in some more google results when searching for "zxing READ_PHONE_STATE".

My questions - If I use zxing only for camera scanning barcode into EditText (The user can type there, or scan the code)

1. Which of the following permissions is **realy** needed, and have to be accepted (except for the obvious android.permission.CAMERA)

- - permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- - permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- - permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

2. What zxing feature would fail if I do not include these permissions?

---

[This question is following my previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54694818/where-can-i-find-more-info-about-android-specific-permissions]

Answer (score 0):

Zxing was once a project in github, and the developers were needed to copy&paste the project files.

6 years forward, we have gradle for automatic imports and Android-libraries can define their own manifest, so the importing project doesn't need to get dirty with those permissions.

Delete all the old zxing code, delete all.of those permissions, import
Zxing Android embedded
(https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded, apache license)
And replace all current calls in your code to the new zxing import. That's it :)

Also,  consider using google's barcode API instead, Google's code can find a barcode in up to 6x faster times then zxing. It was released about 3-4 years ago (I think) so it makes sense your old code doesn't use it.

https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview